# Values of Fabric.js canvas coordinates change when canvas is repositioned

Tags: javascript, css, fabricjs

Consider the following code in the body tag:

```
<div id='div1'></div>
<canvas id='c1' width='1000px', height='400px'></canvas>
```

Now, under the script tag,

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c1');

canvas.on('mouse:down', getMouse);
function getMouse(ev)
{
var pointer = canvas.getPointer(ev.e);
var origX = pointer.x;
var origY = pointer.y;
console.log(origX+', '+origY);
}
```

Under the style tag,

```
#div1
{
float: right;
position: relative;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 1px;
height: 200px;
width: 200px;
display: inline;
}
```

The console logs negative values of y every time I click above the lower line of the bounding box of the div element. Why? What is the fix?

Also, I would like to ideally have the canvas in the center of the page flanked by two  elements on both sides I followed the CSS given here: http://alistapart.com/article/holygrail

What happens is that the div elements are both hidden by the canvas wrapper. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
canvas.calcOffset()
```

is what you need..

Whenever you reposition canvas call the above method.

This calculates canvas element offset relative to the document.

This method is also attached as "resize" event handler of window.

Also for an `object` when changing position/dimension -related properties (left, top, scale, angle, etc.) 
 `set` does not update position of object's borders/controls.

If you need to update those, call:

`setCoords()`.

Comment: For example, http://jsfiddle.net/anirudhrantsandraves/ULk89/

It needs to be run on a bigger screen for the bug to be apparent.

Comment: It was working when there was no text inside the div element. I need the width, height and radius fields to dynamically update in the div as I resize shapes in the canvas.

Comment: I recommend running my code in Chrome. I am not able to select the rectangle I draw when I have a canvas that large which I need for my application. kangax, you might want to take a look at this.

Comment: I fixed it. Called canvas.calcOffset() upon loading the DOM. <body onload = 'calOffset()'>
function calOffset()
{canvas.calcOffset();}